# How to change Firebase Crash Reporting Email Language

Tags: email, firebase, settings, firebase-crash-reporting

I set up `Crash Reporting` in my app and receiving the report email in `English` a week ago. However, for the last 4 days, the email changed to `Japanese`. Howe to change the language back to `English`?

`Email:`
[image]

In `Firebase Console` -> `Alert subscriptions`, there are option to receive or not receive email. But not the language.

`Alert subscriptions:`
[image]

And my Default Language in Google account is `English - United States`

`Google Account:`
[image]

Comment: Sorry you're having problems with this.  It's a known problem, and the Firebase team is expecting a fix to become available in the near future.

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson for the reply. Will wait for the update then.

Answer (score 0):

According @DougStevenson, it's a known bug and Firebase team is working on it.

[Doug Stevenson's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44396659?noredirect=1#comment75800129_44396659)